# Cannot declare class, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to get data from my GraphQL but it returns this error:

```
{
  "message": "Cannot declare class App\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\AcceptBooking, because the name is already in use",
  "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
  "file": "/Users/stevenvaneck/projects/hihiguide/app/Http/GraphQL/Mutations/AcceptBooking.php",
  "line": 14,
  "trace": []
}
```

AcceptBooking.php

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Mutations;

use Auth;
use App\Booking;
use App\Http\Controllers\Email\MailType;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use App\Http\Controllers\Email\MailController;
use App\Jobs\Mail\Traveler\SendNewAvailableMail;
use App\Jobs\SMS\SendNewAvailableSMS;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

class AcceptBooking
{
    /**
     * Return a value for the field.
     *
     * @param null $rootValue Usually contains the result returned from the parent field. In this case, it is always `null`.
     * @param array $args The arguments that were passed into the field.
     * @param GraphQLContext|null $context Arbitrary data that is shared between all fields of a single query.
     * @param ResolveInfo $resolveInfo Information about the query itself, such as the execution state, the field name, path to the field from the root, and more.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function resolve($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context = null, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
    {

      //my code

    }
}
```

If I change the name of the class to something random it again says that the new name I gave it is in use.

In my schema.graphql

```
type Mutation {
    acceptBooking(data: AcceptInput): String @middleware(checks: ["auth:api"]) @field(resolver: "App\\Http\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\AcceptBooking@resolve")
    declineBooking(data: DeclineInput): String @middleware(checks: ["auth:api"]) @field(resolver: "App\\Http\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\DeclineBooking@resolve")
}
```

I'm using Lighthouse-php in a Laravel project.

Comment: It sounds like file is being included (required) more than once.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` in terminal

Comment: Please include the text of error messages in your question.

Answer (score 3):

My namespace path was incorrect

```
namespace App\GraphQL\Mutations;
```

had to be

```
namespace App\GraphQL\Http\Mutations;
```

Comment: Had the same problem, because my class was in a subfolder. Context: Laravel 7 view components. I like to manage views in subfolders for different things. Gotta be careful with the namespaces if you move manually